# Realtime math input in browser

Tags: javascript, html, math

This is a follow up to a [previous, unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41520685/good-browsers-mathjax-and-contenteditable-div) question of mine.

**Goal**: an input field in a web page (the general sense, not a form specifically) where input of certain patters, such as $\int$, will render math - an integral sign in this case, **within the field itself**, not in a separate preview box.

In the linked question I linked to a `conteneteditable` div implementation with MathJax I attempted, but failed (works somewhat on IE, which doesn't count). Please no lip on how `contenteditable` is terrible, I know this very well now.

I came across the [IXL](https://www.ixl.com/math/calculus/find-derivatives-of-polynomials) website, which they have an interesting implementation which works nicely for superscripts and fractions (at least). After answering a few questions you get a toolbar, but you can type Shift+^ to see a superscript immediately.

I think I can expand this for other things I need, but I'm not sure what in their code does this - it looks like a canvas, but I'm not sure, and I was hoping someone smarter can recognize immediately what they're using. The source of the page has the JS.

I've posted on MathJax GitHub and some other tools to advance a solution, but currently no one has this functionality properly (only the 'preview' box).
SO is my final attempt - the diversity of people here hopefully can get me started. I just need to focus my reading - the first lines of code, how is a fraction rendered as that box over line over box in the input field.

I apologize for not posting code of my own, my previous question was my best attempt so far.

Comment: Have you looked into [Guppy](https://github.com/daniel3735928559/guppy).

Comment: You basically want to implement http://wiki.lyx.org/uploads/LyX/Screencasts/LyXIntroPalette.htm via JavaScript?

Comment: @le_m Already did what I need:) Thanks for reminding me of this.

Comment: @jiggzson and thanks to you for Guppy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per jiggzson's suggestion, I checkout out Guppy, forked it and it's awesome (as far as my needs). You can check my fork at https://github.com/uperetz/guppy. I'll post my latest demo there now. Current branch is `textmix` but I'm hoping Daniel will merge to master.